# POST args to method rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, post

I'm trying to wrap my head around forms on rails and am attempting to implement a very simple registration page. Essentially, it's going to take a name and an email, sterilise the parameters and then chuck it into MySQL.

I have this code for generating the form:

```
  <%= form_tag(controller: "root", action: "register", method: "post", class: "root") do %>
      <%= label_tag(:n, "Name:") %>
      <%= email_field(:n, "name") %>
      <%= label_tag(:e, "Email:") %>
      <%= email_field(:e, "email") %>
      <%= submit_tag("Register") %>
  <% end %>
```

Which seems to work, this is the route:

```
  post '/' => 'root#register'
```

Which also seems to work fine, and this is the controller:

```
class RootController < ApplicationController
  def root

  end

  def register(name,email)

  end
end
```

However, I receive the following error, so I'm wondering how I stick my args into my POST request so that they get passed to the method.

[image: Error Screenie]

I've had a look around Google and can't seem to get an answer.

Comment: how do you learn rails, I wonder? _Any_ rails tutorial (to not mention books) explains how to handle parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's now you handle parameters in rails. This is how.

```
def register
  name = params[:name]
  email = params[:email]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question! Would you mind explaining exactly how this works for future visitors? For instance, why do normal ruby params not work?

Comment: @JamesHughes: don't worry, future visitors are unlikely to ever find your question. It's ungooglable and once it stops receiving edits and other activity, it will be lost in history. :) As for the explanation: controller actions are not your "ordinary" methods. You don't call them directly and, therefore, they're allowed to accept input however they want. As I mentioned in the comment above, this matter should be well explained in any rails book.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably just get a book rather than relying on my other programming knowledge to try and ad-hoc it...

Comment: @JamesHughes: books are structured knowledge. 10/10, highly recommend :)